# How do i alter the name of a default home page in the breadcrumb in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, breadcrumbs

I'm customizing a team site in SharePoint 2010 and have been tweaking the breadcrumb to include a link back to the root. Now it says "Home > Home" for the main site and all subsites. How do i rename the home page so that it isn't called "Home" in the breadcrumb?

I tried creating a new page and naming it the way i wanted, and it worked until i set it to the home page. SharePoint overrides your title name with home EVERY time. Anybody know a way around this so that i can turn this automatic renaming off? I'm open to hacks.

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is an option for you then use it. You will need to construct the selector to get to the **Home** node and replace it with whatever text you need. For example,

Let's assume you have the following HTML for the breadcrumb:

```
<ul class="breadCrumb">
    <li class="breadCrumbNode"><a title="Home" href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadCrumbNode"><span class="breadCrumbArrow">&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="breadCrumbNode"><a title="Page1" href="">Page1</a></li>
    <li class="breadCrumbNode"><span class="breadCrumbArrow">&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="breadCrumbNode"><span class="breadCrumbCurrentNode">This Page</span></li>
</ul>
```

Your JavaScript would be:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.breadCrumbNode>a[title=Home]').text('New Title for Home Page');
});
```

See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kDa2h/2/) (jsfiddle.net)